# Where to put util function?

Tags: django

I have a utility function that interprets scores in an object and returns a string. I want to display the strings it computes for each object. How do I get this to the template?

**views.py**

```
def foo(bar):
    if bar.score >= 42:
        return "Oh yes!"
    else:
        return "Nooo!"

def home(request):
    bars = Bar.objects.all()
    # Do something with foo() and all the bars for our template to use?
    return render_to_response("home.html", 
                                locals(),
                                context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How do I get access to `foo(bar)` from `home.html`?

Comment: You should probably read [Custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-template-tags/) in the Django documentation.

Comment: @lanzz erased my answer because that is probably what he's looking for.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make foo a model method?

Comment: And how would the template use it?

Comment: @lanzz That is the coolest thing ever! I got it working now (with my actual much larger function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you can simply add a property to your model to call in the template. A custom template tag is probably overkill, because you can accomplish the same result with less code just leveraging the model:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def foo(self):
        if self.score >= 42:
            return "Oh yes!"
        return "Nooo!"
```

Comment: THIS IS WAY BETTER. Thanks.

Comment: And to use it in the template: `{{ bar.foo }}`